# How to delete master branch and rename other branch master?

Tags: github

I have two branches, master and testing. I need to delete the master branch and then rename testing to master and set that as the default. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several ways to do this, using the WebUI or using Git. However the issue you'll have here is that you cannot delete the default branch and the default branch is usually `master`. Regardless of what option you go with, **please do clone a fresh version of the repository to another folder so you don't accidentally mess up**.

**Using the WebUI:**

1. Follow this [guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-the-default-branch) to change the default branch to be testing
2. Delete `master` from the branches view
3. Go to the branch dropdown and while on `testing` start typing `master` and GitHub will offer to branch from `testing` to `master`. At this point they are the same, i.e., they point to the exact same commit.
4. Go back to the guide mentioned in (1) and change the default branch to `master`
5. Delete `testing` from the branches view.

**Using Git** (assuming local repository is up to date with upstream):

1. Run `git push origin testing:master -f`
2. Delete `testing`: `git push origin :testing`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: can you explain what step 1 of using git is doing exactly? and what does -f do?

Comment: The command is `git push <remote name> <local branch>:<remote branch>` it pushes to remote name. Which can be a remote url or another folder. By default it's wherever you cloned from. Local branch is the name of the local branch you want to push. Remote branch is the name of the branch you want to push to on the server. By default you usually have an upstream branch that's set to the same name as the local branch. `git checkout` does this for you. So git push will by default push the current branch to it's upstream branch which usually is on origin and has the same name as the local branch.

Comment: For example `git push origin develop:develop` The `-f` is forcing the push because you will likely get an error without it. The error is because you'll be changing the history of the master branch. Unless your branch is ahead of the master commit and the push can fast-forward to your the head of your local branch. It sounds complicated, but try it without -f and you'll get the error message. Read it and it'll explain. Then add the -f to go ahead. In this case it's pushing the local testing branch to origin and overwriting the master branch on origin.

Comment: The second command effectively deletes the remote testing branch by passing a null branch to origin and overwriting it's testing branch. You'll still have your local copy of testing which you can delete with `git branch -D testing` as long as you're not on that branch. I had to split this into separate comments because of the 600 char length limit.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably simplest to switch the name of the branch you want to make the new master locally, and then force-push it; while we're at it, we can back up the old master just in case.

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m testing master
# old master saved, new master is now `master`

git push -f origin master
# master overridden in the repo

git push -f origin old-master
git branch -d old-master
# Old master backed up, removed locally
```

Remember that anyone collaborating with you will need to resolve any conflicts they have between their branches and the new master.

The `old-master` branch takes up very little space on the server, so it's a good safety net in case there's some reason we really, really have to fall back to it. You'd do something similar to what we just did here to restore it.

```
git branch -m master erroneous-master
git checkout -b master origin/old-master
git push -f master origin/master
git push -f erroneous-master origin/erroneous-master
```

We save the bad master for the same reason; we may want to salvage things from it.
A `git push origin :branch-to-remove` will get rid of unneeded branches at a later date, when you're certain you won't need them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine for me! Just had to do ```git branch -D old-master```, which is fine as I really only need a remote safety copy.